# Cordova jquery insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cordova, jquery-mobile

First I'm very new to cordova and mobile app development so I'm not sure if there is any dependencies/plug-ins I'm missing. I'm following tutorials but not much info on all the pugins needed etc. I'm just testing communication to my remote mysql database using android studio emulator with the following script.

When running my app I just get my error function alert "There was an error" telling me my code is not breaking but not inserting my data.

I also believe my config.xml is allowing connections to all addresses.

I have also tested it in browser with fixed values to ensure there is not a problem with my php code.

I feel my app is not connecting/communicating with my remote url.

Thanks for the help

index.html Cordova local

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src &apos;self&apos; data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com &apos;unsafe-eval&apos;; style-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos;; media-src *; img-src &apos;self&apos; data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-1.5.0.mobile.min.css">
        <style>
        /* For avoiding title truncation in wp8 */
        .ui-header .ui-title {
                overflow: visible !important;
        }
        /* For fixing the absolute position issue for the default cordova gen page*/
        #cjp-accordion1 .app {
                left: 5px !important;
                margin: 5px !important;
                position: relative !important;
        }
        </style>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="write your first name" id="firstname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="write your last name" id="lastname">
    <button id="sub">Submit result</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" id="cordova-jquery"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.0.mobile.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/insert.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

insert.js Cordova local

```
$("#sub").on("click", function(){
var firstname=$("#firstname").val();
var lastname=$("#lastname").val();
var dataString="firstname="+firstname+"&lastname="+lastname;
alert(dataString);
                if($.trim(firstname).length >0 & $.trim(lastname).length >0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",  //Request type
                        data:{firstname:firstname, lastname:lastname},
                        url: "http://www.urlToRemoteServer.co.za/insert.php",
                        cache:false,
                        success:function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            alert('Con Success');
                        },
                        error:function(data)
                        {
                            console.log(data);
                            alert('There was an error');
                        }
                    })
                }
                else {
                    alert('Input fields are empty');
                }
});
```

insert.php on my remote web server

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

$config = parse_ini_file('config/config.ini'); 
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($config['server'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname'],3306);
if($firstname){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `cordova_test` (`firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname')";
 $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if($result) {
        echo $firstname." ".$lastname;
    } 
    else {
        echo "unable to insert data";
    }
}
else{
echo "No Data"; 
}
?>
```

config.xml Cordova local

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.psimation.jquery" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>jquery</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention that my php code is 100%. I have tested it in browser with fixed values to ensure there is not a problem with my php code.

Comment: I ran my code from my browser just to test again. Interesting from my browser it's inserting my data into my database but it still alerting the error message although my data was inserted into the db. So my conclusion is that I cannot connect to remote server via android emulator and why I'm getting the error alert is still a headache.